# Manually set selectedObject in Angucomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how can we do that?
The problem is that ng-model is hard coded to searchStr and selectedObject is readonly.

Is there similar component for autocomplete for angular JS. Angucomplete is great because it can be connected with JSON response.

**Solution**

use [angcomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt), it has a lot of extra features and "initial-value" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Angucomplete is a component, in this you can set Initial value.

Please check below links for it.

http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete

Comment: Thats exactly the problem, i can't set the initial value in angucomplete. I checked angucomplete-alt and this one has this option